# CSS3 @font-face Not Rendering Font in Opera 11.x

Tags: css, opera, font-face

I'm running into an issue with Opera not rendering my HTML5 site properly. The site and my @font-face are working perfectly in Safari, Chrome, IE9, Firefox 3.5+, etc.  I'm wondering if someone has run into this issue before and how they fixed it.  Here's a breakdown of my code:

In the root I have a folder called fonts.  This folder has all my font files and a stylesheet called stylesheet.css that looks like this:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'LeagueGothicRegular';
    src: url('League_Gothic-webfont.eot');
    src: url('League_Gothic-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('League_Gothic-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('League_Gothic-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('League_Gothic-webfont.svg#LeagueGothicRegular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

My home page is referencing this stylesheet accordingly:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="fonts/stylesheet.css" type="text/css"/>
```

I have a menu that looks similar to this:

```
<nav>
    <div class="main_nav">
        <div class="nav_button">
            <ul>
                <li class="red"><a href="index.htm">HOME</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="about.htm">ABOUT</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="history.htm">History</a></li>
                                <li><a href="management.htm">Management</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
            ...
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

My styles for this menu in another file look like this:

```
.nav_button {height:110px; margin:0px 1px 0px 0px; font: 34px 'LeagueGothicRegular', Arial, sans-serif; letter-spacing: 0; line-height:34px; float:left;}

.nav_button ul { 
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    display:block;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    list-style: none;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.nav_button ul li { 
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    padding: 0px;

    float: left;
    position: relative;
    list-style: none;
}
```

Again, this code works fine in other browsers, it's just barking in Opera 11.x and not rendering.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It would be helpful if you put up a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) as an example.  (Or link to an example on your own server.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can happen sometimes when the font file is served with an unknown or unexpected content type header.

Verify that your WOFF and TTF files are being served with an `Content-Type: "application/octet-stream"` header.

If you're using Apache, add the following to your .htaccess file.

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  <FilesMatch "\.woff$">
     Header set Content-Type "application/octet-stream"
  </FilesMatch>

  <FilesMatch "\.ttf$">
     Header set Content-Type application/octet-stream
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

(And please post a jsFiddle of your code above if this doesn't work.)

Comment: so TTF works great but WOFF was returning a 404.  I started checking the headers and found IIS7 by default doesn't have a MIME type for WOFF.  Once I added it, everything clicked.  Thanks!