# Opera doesn't display outside fonts

Tags: css, fonts, font-face, opera

Next problem - Opera doesn't display outside fonts. Next code:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "Ubuntu-Italic"; 
    src:url('../fonts/Ubuntu-I.eot'),
    src:url('../fonts/Ubuntu-I.eot?#iefix') format('opentype'),
    src:url('../fonts/Ubuntu-I.woff') format('woff'),
    src:url('../fonts/Ubuntu-I.otf') format('opentype'),
    src:url('../fonts/Ubuntu-I.ttf') format('truetype'),
    src:url('../fonts/Ubuntu-I.svg') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Looks like all ok - double quotes, "woff" format... But it doesn't work for Opera.

Comment: There's tons of this @ StackOverflow, for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9506837/css3-font-face-not-rendering-font-in-opera-11-x

Comment: pc-shooter, cache was cleared, and fonts are not from Google-Fonts
arma, thank u, now i'm trying to understand this one, all i read before at this topic were unusable.

Answer (score 0):

The attribute src needs a URL list.
Or use multiple src defintitions.
You mixed it. It is not valid CSS.

Your code:

```
src:url('../fonts/Ubuntu-I.eot'),
src:url('../fonts/Ubuntu-I.eot?#iefix') format('opentype'),
src:url('../fonts/Ubuntu-I.woff') format('woff'),
src:url('../fonts/Ubuntu-I.otf') format('opentype'),
src:url('../fonts/Ubuntu-I.ttf') format('truetype'),
src:url('../fonts/Ubuntu-I.svg') format('svg');
```

Should be:

```
src:url('../fonts/Ubuntu-I.eot'),
    url('../fonts/Ubuntu-I.eot?#iefix') format('opentype'),
    url('../fonts/Ubuntu-I.woff') format('woff'),
    url('../fonts/Ubuntu-I.otf') format('opentype'),
    url('../fonts/Ubuntu-I.ttf') format('truetype'),
    url('../fonts/Ubuntu-I.svg') format('svg');
```

And the correct MIME-Type is sent for the different types?